# Notation: How to indicate a segment of vector

Tags: notation, vectors

How to note a segment (a part) of a larger vector?

Say I have

$$
\vec{x} = \begin{pmatrix}x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & x_5\end{pmatrix}
$$

And I want to extract a specific section:

$$
\vec{y} = \begin{pmatrix}x_2 & x_3 & x_4\end{pmatrix}
$$

Is there a clear and generally accepted notation for this?
Basically what in MATLAB or Python would be `y = x[2:4]`.

Would any reader understand $y=x_{2:4}$?

Comment: This looks strikingly similar to [the restriction of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_(mathematics)), but I don't know if something similar exists for a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can represent the vector $\vec{x}$ using index  notation:
\begin{align*}
\vec{x}=\left(x_j\right)_{1\leq j \leq 5}
\end{align*}
The vector $\vec{y}$ can then be written as
\begin{align*}
\vec{y}=\left(x_j\right)_{2\leq j\leq 4}
\end{align*}
In general we can write using index sets  $S\subset T$:
\begin{align*}
\vec{x}=\left(x_j\right)_{j\in T}\qquad\qquad \vec{y}=\left(x_j\right)_{j\in S}
\end{align*}

Comment: Accepting this answer, though [@miracle173](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3748332/686881)'s answer is also very useful

Comment: @Roberto: Thanks, you're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The mapping
$$\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \\ x_5\end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix} x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \end{pmatrix} $$
is linear, so there is a matrix that represents this linear mapping:

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0&0  \\ 0&0&0&1&0  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \\ x_5\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \end{pmatrix} $$

---

I would not expect that a reader understands $y=x_{2:4}$ but you can define your symbols before you use them.

Answer (score 1):

You can write $y= Px$, where $P$ is the projection operator to the subspace you wish (the $x_2,x_3,x_4$ space in your example).

An equivalent expression would be $\vec{y} = (\vec{x} \cdot \hat{x}_2)\hat{x}_2+\dotsb $

Using the second method, we should denote the coordinates in the space of $\vec{y}$ differently: $u_1,u_2,\dotsc$, so in your example we actually have:
$$
 \vec{y} = (\vec{x} \cdot \hat{x}_2)\hat{u}_1+ (\vec{x} \cdot \hat{x}_3)\hat{u}_2+ (\vec{x} \cdot \hat{x}_4)\hat{u}_3.
$$

Comment: It seems that the OP wants to reduce the dimension of their vector while they remove the first component. Would a projection operator achieve that? It seems that we should get $(0, x_{2}, x_{3}, x_{4})$ instead.

Comment: No I think what @RdBasha suggests would work. If P were not square it would reduce the dimensions like that.  
However, I was hoping there is something more convenient. If I need to use many of these operations, combined with other matrix multiplications, it will quickly become cluttered.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine, faced with
$$
f : X \to Y \tag{1}\\ 
A \subset X
$$
would write
$$
f|A : A \to Y \tag{2}
$$
to indicate the restriction of $f$ to the subset $A$, an operation that came up frequently in topology. I think that if you defined $2:4$ to mean the segment of the natural numbers between $2$ and $4$ (inclusive), you could write
$$
(x|2:4)
$$
without a lot of ambiguity, although it's not pretty.

One problem is that the colon is already used in function notation, as in equation 1 above; another is that one wants the "|" operator to bind tightly, so that you can write things like
$$
f|A \times g| B
$$
for a product of restricted functions. That means you'd need to write
$$
x|(2:4)
$$
which is even less pretty. And if you wanted to indicate that this restricted thing took values in the reals, you'd need to write
$$
x|(2:4) : (2:4) \to \Bbb R
$$
which is downright ugly.

In short: you can use this "colon" notation (if you define it carefully), but it's likely to ugly up your writing a bit. This is the rare case where I'd favor subscript notation over the kind of functional notation in equation 2 above.